# save picture in cloud

Tags: c#, http, rest

I am saving data on Buddy cloud. Earlier I was saving string data and it was fine. Now I have to save picture but I am getting exception "Bad Request". Actually, they specify that its type should be "file". I don't know how to specify that. Below is the code and I have to do this using API.
documentation: http://dev.buddyplatform.com/Home/Docs/Create%20Picture/HTTP?

```
        byte[] image = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);

        string url = "https://api.buddyplatform.com/pictures";

        // how to specify type below line ? how to correct ?
        string parameters = "{data:'" + image + "'}";

        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Buddy " + SharedData.buddyTOKEN);

            // send request
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync());
            sw.WriteLine(parameters);
            sw.Close();

            // get response
            response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to create the request body (your `parameters` string) by concatenating a string with a `byte[]`.  This will end up calling `ToString()` on a `byte[]`, leaving you with a request that looks like:

```
{ data:'System.Byte[]' }
```

Since this is being sent as a JSON request, it's likely that Buddy is expecting a base64 encoded file.  This is how you would encode your file in base64 and insert it into the request:

```
string parameters = "{data:'" + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes) + "'}";
```

Result:

```
{data:'FxgZGurnIBlBCtIAIQ[...rest of your file...]'}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply @tbridge, now I am getting exception "Bad Request" while calling for response "GetResponseAsync(); please help me. Thank you very much for your reply again!

Comment: @user3102858 You should investigate what format they are expecting the image to be in, `base64` was just a guess.